# Transfer SORM Instance to remote akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, sorm

How i can get the clear instance of my class from the inside of the SORM object wrapper?
On send a wrapper to remote actor it causes an ClassNotFoundException:

```
[ERROR] ... Error __wrapper$1$28457a083cbf41f3a038257f7813a4f7.__wrapper$1$28457a083cbf41f3a038257f7813a4f7$PersistedAnonymous1$1] [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: __wrapper$1$28457a083cbf41f3a038257f7813a4f7.__wrapper$1$28457a083cbf41f3a038257f7813a4f7$PersistedAnonymous1$1
```

How to do it right? I transfer a new instance of the class, but I do not find it elegant. copy() method isn't helps.

Comment: I've implemented this feature in "0.3.9-SNAPSHOT" release. For details check out the appropriate [feature request](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/18). Please use-test this feature and post your feedback.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Yes, it works. But it's uncomfortable, because I would like to save id object when it is transmitted. Have to be stored on a map that links the object and its id on the server side or transmit it in tuple with id.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Alternatively, entities should be allowed to have the id column and then not to mix them with the Persisted? Then the wrappers are not needed.

Comment: I've made a new snapshot release. Details are in [the feature request](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/18). Next time please post your feedback there.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is extract a value of a pure type `A` out of a value of type `A with Persisted`. SORM doesn't yet provide any automated facility to achieve that. Though it could be implemented in a form of some kind of specific method on `Persisted`, e.g. `.demixinPersisted`.

I've posted an appropriate [feature request](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/18). You can monitor it from now on.